# Ubuntu 23.10 file dialog is showing corrupted characters in a snap electron app

Tags: snap, 23.10, electron

I have developed an electron app which is in the snap store. It's a simple enough text editor. On Ubuntu 23.10, the electron `showOpenDialog` command is opening a filesystem file picker with corrupt characters.

This is reproducible across 23.10 installations, and doesn't seem to happen to other apps on an affected machine.

Any idea what the cause could be?

[image]

I'm using the latest version of electron in the app (27.0.2) and not doing anything odd in code - pretty much using the example code provided by electron documentation. Why is are the filenames all corrupted?

The dialog also appears to return blank file paths if you click on something.

Comment: Also ask at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/ Many snap developers are present there.